# iOS Custom App Salesforce - SSL Error while trying to connect to salesforce on 4G

Tags: ios, ssl, ipad, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

We have an iOS iPad app which is built using Salesforce Mobile SDK. Last two days we are facing issues while syncing work back to Salesforce. When they try to sync, it shows this error,

**"Server Error - Can't connect to server. An SSL error has occured and a secure connection the server cannot be made."**

It works absolutely fine when connected to wifi and sync the data. Also there seems to be no problem while using hotspot from a mobile data. Has anyone faced this issue and know what might be causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add below in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why is it happening only when using 4G and not on wifi?

Comment: I will try it out, but it is long process. I will keep you posted.

Comment: why it is long process?